# How to verify service.methodA called in service.methodB from controller test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I have got 2 methods in my service which are findAccount and credit. credit method internally calls findAccount. What I would like to manage is to verify how many times findAccount is called in my CONTROLLER test

Here is my classes

My service impl is:

```
@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

    private static final String CLASS_NAME = AccountServiceImpl.class.getSimpleName();
    
    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private final AccountRepository accountRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    public AccountServiceImpl(AccountRepository accountRepository) {
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
    }
    
    @Override
    public TransactionStatus credit(String accountNumber, Transaction trx) {
        log.info("{} -> credit -> accountNumber: {}, trx: {}",CLASS_NAME, accountNumber, trx);
        
        Account account = findAccount(accountNumber);
        trx.setAccount(account);
        
        TransactionStatus trxStatus = new TransactionStatus();
        try {
            account.post(trx);
            trxStatus.setApprovalCode(trx.getApprovalCode().toString());
        } catch (InsufficientBalanceException e) {
            log.error("InsufficientBalanceException is occured: {}", e.getMessage());
            trxStatus.setStatus(BankingConstants.NOT_OK);
        }
        return trxStatus;
    }

    @Override
    public TransactionStatus debit(String accountNumber, Transaction trx) throws InsufficientBalanceException {
        log.info("{} -> debit -> accountNumber: {}, trx: {}",CLASS_NAME, accountNumber, trx);
        Account account = findAccount(accountNumber);
        trx.setAccount(account);
        TransactionStatus trxStatus = new TransactionStatus();

        account.post(trx);

        return trxStatus;
    }

    @Override
    public Account findAccount(String accountNumber) {
        log.info("{} -> findAccount -> accountNumber: {}",CLASS_NAME, accountNumber);
        return accountRepository.findByAccountNumber(accountNumber).orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
    }

}
```

Controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account/v1")
public class AccountController {

    private final AccountService accountService;
    
    @Autowired
    public AccountController(AccountService accountService) {
        this.accountService = accountService;
    }
    
    @PostMapping(path = "/credit/{accountNumber}")
    public ResponseEntity<TransactionStatus> credit(@PathVariable String accountNumber, @RequestBody DepositTransaction depositTransaction) throws InsufficientBalanceException {
        TransactionStatus response = accountService.credit(accountNumber, depositTransaction);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response,HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/debit/{accountNumber}")
    public ResponseEntity<TransactionStatus> debit(@PathVariable String accountNumber, @RequestBody WithdrawalTransaction withdrawalTransaction) throws InsufficientBalanceException {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(accountService.debit(accountNumber, withdrawalTransaction),HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/{accountNumber}")
    public ResponseEntity<Account> getAccount(@PathVariable String accountNumber) {
        Account result = accountService.findAccount(accountNumber);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

and here is my controller test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class ControllerTests {

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    private AccountController controller;
 
    @Mock
    private AccountService service;

    
@Test
public void givenId_Credit_thenReturnJson() throws Exception {

    Account account = new Account("Kerem Karaca", "17892");
    doReturn(account).when(service).findAccount("17892");
    ResponseEntity<TransactionStatus> result = controller.credit("17892", new DepositTransaction(1000.0));
    verify(service, times(1)).findAccount("17892");
    assertEquals("OK", result.getBody().getStatus());
    assertEquals(1000.0, account.getBalance(), 0.001);
}
```

}

Comment: I have a sneaky suspicion it is down to the way you are calling the service, I think `doReturn(account).when(service).findAccount("17892");` does not actually call the method, but using `when(service).findAccount("17892").thenReturn(account);` should.

Comment: As your test creates your full Spring Context, you should rather use `@MockBean` here if you want to replace a bean with a mocked version of it. `@Mock` helps you when writing [unit tests without any Spring Test Context support](https://rieckpil.de/difference-between-mock-and-mockbean-spring-boot-applications/).

Answer (score 0):

You're mocking the Service, so when the controller calls credit, you're not executing the implementation of that routine.

It looks to me that what you want is to write a test for the service, mock the repository, and then verify that when you call credit on the service, the repository findByAccountNumber routine is called once.